# why we can not reference a pointer but values

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reference(int &ref){
    cout << ref << endl;
}

void pointer(int *ref){
    cout << *ref << endl;
}

int main(){
    int *i = new int[1];
    *i = 10;
    reference(*i);  // fine
    reference(i);   // why not compiling!!! why not referencing to my pointer??
    pointer(i);     // fine
}
```

I want to reference a pointer, as i can see i am allowed to reference value but not pointer, why??

Comment: Well you can: `void pointer(int*& ref){`. It's a bit unclear what you're actually asking for.

Comment: It doesn't crash, it's a compile error.

Comment: but why down vote, it seems valid question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object of type `int*` cannot be automatically converted to `int&`.

I think you are looking for something like:

```
void reference(int& ref){
    cout << ref << endl;
}

void reference(int*& ref){
    cout << *ref << endl;
}
```

Then, you can use both:

```
int main(){
    int *i = new int[1];
    *i = 10;
    reference(*i);
    reference(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then the first call to reference will not work!

Comment: You need both in that case.

Comment: ... And return a value from main¬

Comment: @EdHeal You don't need to return from main.

Comment: @NeilKirk - 1. It is good practice. 2. Gets you into the habit of returning from every function that does not return void

Comment: @EdHeal 1. Subjective. 2. I'm already in the habit and if I forget, my compiler tells me.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 reference(i);
```

is trying to pass in a `int *` - not an ``int` variable. Hence will not compile.

See the signature of the function

Answer (score 1):

First of all "crash" is a term you can only use after getting through compiler...

```
void reference(int &ref)
```

This function is taking reference to integer as its parameter while you are passing pointer to integer through

```
reference(i)
```

Change your function's signature to something like:-

```
void reference(int* &ref)
```

for this call to work. OR change call to something like:-

```
int i;
reference(i);
```

for this function to work.

Comment: yes i meant this only.. what function parameters type should i use to get reference of pointer to int, thanks